# Azure Web App node.js deploy fails

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

We tried to deploy a new node.js version on Azure Web App.
A new source version is retrieved from our git repository on push.

It seems like some of the files remain locked and blocking our new deployment, what can we do, and can we avoid it in the future?
(the locked file is an NPM library so it has nothing to do with the app code)

```
updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
npm WARN package.json express-livereload@0.0.24 No repository field.
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, unlink 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure_util\node_modules\pkgcloud\node_modules\aws-sdk\apis'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, unlink 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\azure_util\node_modules\pkgcloud\node_modules\aws-sdk\apis']
npm ERR!   errno: 50,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\node_modules\\azure_util\\node_modules\\pkgcloud\\node_modules\\aws-sdk\\apis' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.10.32\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.4.28\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
Failed exitCode=50, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.32\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.4.28\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
npm ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

Comment: What's the actual command you're running?

Comment: I don't run any command, I'm deploying a node.js app connected to our BitBucket repository

Comment: Well the error you're seeing is related to running `npm`. Specifically it appears to be related to running `npm` without elevated privileges. How are you deploying it? You must be typing something or doing something that triggers the deployment.

Comment: Azure Web App can be connected to a node.js Git repository and whenever a new commit is pushed an automatic new deployment is trigger pulling the new code, calling npm install and running the app.

Comment: I see. OK, so my first thought is that NPM doesn't have the right permissions to run - but if you added a new module to your git repo, it's trying to run and failing.

Comment: I didn't add any new module, I managed to overcome the issue. I connected the machine using ftp and deleted the locked folder, and then redeployed... How can I avoid it?

Comment: It's not a normal error. Maybe next time try editing the permissions on the locked folder instead?

Comment: I don't want to have to do anything, it should not have leave any lock...

Comment: No, it shouldn't - maybe it was a one-off fluke? But if it keeps happening, then your only option is to do that. Unless you can find a way to give your deployment hook elevated privileges.

Comment: Guy - What package is that? Why is it trying to do a link? You need administrator privileges to do that. One near term work around is to deploy the packages themselves, don't rely on Websites to deploy for you.

Comment: It could be locked because the node is still running.  You might verify if the nodes are being brought down before the new code is applied.  If you watch a typical Heroku or OpenShift push it brings down the running nodes before replacing with the new version.  Couldn't tell you about the Azure Web App hosting, though.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web App and file locks are annoying, stopping or resetting an slot will not remove any file locks.

The only way to remove this file lock at command is to swap the slot with another one.