# Node.JS WebApp deployment fails with unclear error

Tags: node.js, azure

I was not having any problem with my web app. I made a change in the code and commited the code. The Build failed. So I went back to the last working commit where the build was successful and it failed again. I am receiving the following error which does not tell me what I should do.

Any Ideas?

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: '.DS_Store'
Copying file: 'app.js'
Copying file: 'package.json'
Copying file: 'bin\www'
Copying file: 'js\auth.js'
Copying file: 'js\chargeServer.js'
Copying file: 'js\helper.js'
Copying file: 'js\requiresLogin.js'
Copying file: 'js\setup-passport.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\.bin\needle'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\.editorconfig'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\.jshintrc'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\.npmignore'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\.travis.yml'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\DEVELOPMENT.md'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\LICENSE'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\package.json'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\README.md'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\changelog.md'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\LICENSE'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\package.json'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\README.md'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\browser\bluebird.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\browser\bluebird.min.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\any.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\assert.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\async.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\bind.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\bluebird.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\call_get.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\cancel.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\captured_trace.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\catch_filter.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\context.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\debuggability.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\direct_resolve.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\each.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\errors.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\es5.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\filter.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\finally.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\generators.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\join.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\map.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\method.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\nodeify.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\progress.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise.js'
Copying file: 'node_modules\auth0\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promise_array.js'
Omitting next output lines...
Processed 997 files...
Processed 1919 files...
Processed 2706 files...
Processed 3668 files...
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24,     0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3,     4.2.4, 4.3.0, 4.3.2, 4.4.0, 4.4.1, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.8.0, 5.9.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0.
Selected node.js version 5.9.1. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Selected npm version 3.7.3
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
timebro@0.0.0 D:\home\site\wwwroot
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! code 1
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\5.9.1\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.7.3\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-    cli.js" install --production
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
npm ERR! code 1\r\nC:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\55.50620.2286\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd     "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

Comment: Looks there is a locking issue with respect to the deployment folder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598476/azure-web-app-node-js-deploy-fails

Comment: But i don't have any deployment slots

Comment: you must be deploying it somewhere like azure web apps. right?. u can connect to those via ftp or asp.net webmatrix tool and remove the locked folder manually assuming the error that you face is same as the one i tagged.

Comment: But what files should be deleted? What is my locked folder?

Comment: ideally this is not how it should work. you should be able to automatically deploy it.  did u try doing it once again?  in that question they are talking about deleting the entire deployment folder itself.

Comment: I tried multiple times i also went back to commits from other days where everything was fine. I even emptied the who bitbucket resource folder but it would not deploy...

Comment: hmm.. did you try deploying to a different slot ( different web app name ) ?

Comment: I am using a free plan for testing where i do not have multiple slots. But I made another webApp and the error was the same.

Comment: see if this helps https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b59cd03d-666e-45e8-8604-04ace1d7647d/nodejs-unable-to-deploy-nodejs-app?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115708/discussion-between-silve2611-and-aravind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Silve2611 I see the command `...\npm\bin\npm-    cli.js" install --production` in the last third line of your post content has some whitespace which I doubt it caused the issue if it's not human input mistake.

Meanwhile, I suggest you can try to deploy again after removing clean the directory `node_modules`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for the information. Unfortunately i am not the one starting the comand. I am pushing my code to a git repository which is fetched by the azure server. the server than deploys my code. How would I do a removing clean of node_modules?

Comment: @Silve2611 You can use the Kudu Console via access the url `https://<webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and move into the path `site\wwwroot` to remove it manually via the command `rmdir /S /Q node_modules`.

Comment: unfortunately it did not help but thank you for the explanation!

Comment: i updated all my packages and it worked again. you focus on the modules helped me. thx